# Dropdown list and map.fitBounds in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson, jquery

In my Lealfet application I have a dropdown list which uses data from a GeoJSON to directly populate the list.

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputCS"><h6>Seleziona il Foglio</h6></label>
  <select id="fogli-dropdown" name="foglio">
  </select>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
let dropdown = $('#fogli-dropdown');
dropdown.empty();
dropdown.append('<option selected="true" disabled>Seleziona il Foglio</option>');
dropdown.prop('selectedIndex', 0);
var fogli = new L.geoJson(fogli, {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', layer.feature.properties.fg).text(layer.feature.properties.fg));
    }
});
```

According to the select item in the list (fogli) I would like that my map fits the current extent of the selected item.

Comment: Since I'm not familiar with JQuery, I have two questions: (1) Can this `'value'` attribute be any value you want that can be used later? (2) What is callback/event function when dropdown values is selected and how can selected `'value'` attribute be accessed in callback?

Comment: Hi, 1) Is the value of interest of the geojson and 2) The event function should be map.fitbounds.

Comment: You didn't answer my second question. When user select a value from dropdown, how/where do you catch this event and get selected value?